# How to get all function arguments in scala

Tags: scala, reflection

Is there possible to get all function arguments and pass it to another?

```
def function funA(arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: Int): Any = {
  ....
  funB(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}
```

Instead `funB(arg1, arg2, arg3)` I want to write something like this `funB(parentFun.args)`

Is it at all possible? Maybe I should use some reflections?

Answer (score 5):

I assume if you do it more than twice, You should create case class for readability though,You can do

```
def funA(arg:(String,String,Int)): Any = {
  (funB _).tupled(arg)
}
//and call it 
funA("a","b",1)
```

and If you wnat to use `arg1`,`arg2`,`arg3` name inside of `funA`,
you can

```
def funA(arg:(String,String,Int)): Any = {
  val (arg1,arg2,arg3) = arg
  println(arg1) //arg1 is arg._1
  (funB _).tupled(arg)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should keep well away from reflection if your only goal is terseness.

If you have a bunch of alternate functions, all with the same signature you could define them as functions like this:

```
val funB = (arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: Int) => {
   "Foo"
}

val funC = (arg1: String, arg2: String, arg3: Int) => {
  "Bar"
}

def funA(somethingToDecideWhichFunctionToCall: String): (String, String, Int) => String = {
  somethingToDecideWhichFunctionToCall match {
    case "Option 1" => funB
    case "Option 2" => funC
  }
}

def callingThing() = {
  val arg1 = "Foo"
  val arg2 = "Bar"
  val arg3 = 1
  funA("Option 1")(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}
```

Alternatively, if you have a bunch of functions all with the same signature, you could just hide it behind an interface and use good ol' polymorphism.